# jqPlot: Legend at the center of Donut chart

Tags: legend, jqplot, donut-chart

We have implemented Donut chart using jqPlot.
How can we add legend to the center of the Donut chart?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested from jqPlot documentation:  [jqplot deprecated legend offset](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Legend.xoffset)

Set the margins on the legend using the marginTop, marginLeft, etc. properties or via CSS margin styling of the .jqplot-table-legend class.